# memory leaks in my strings

Tags: iphone

I have this in my code :

```
NSString *myString = @"";
....

if (...) {
myString = @" other string";
}
...
myString = @" an other string ";
```

is this a leak, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, guys, but it's not autoreleased. It's not leaked, but it's not autoreleased. This code prove it:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *str1 = @"First one"; // 
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The %dnd", 2]; // this autoreleasing string
[pool drain];

NSLog(@"%@", str1); // All's ok
NSLog(@"%@", str2); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Read about strings created with `@"..."` construction at [Strings PRogramming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW1):

> The compiler makes such object
>   constants unique on a per-module
>   basis, and they’re never deallocated,
>   though you can retain and release them
>   as you do any other object.

Comment: +1:yeah... they all are stored in a constant pool (not auto released pool) and if you check their retain count it's the maximum value that an integer can hold.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a leak it will be `autorelease`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a leak. You leak memory only when you allocate memory and don't release the memory.

In your case what ever you have created is an auto released object. They will be released at a later time.

Comment: No, it's not autoreleased object

Answer (score 1):

You leak memory when you take ownership of the object by allocating them using `alloc init` or `new` , `retain` or `mutablecopy` methods and subsequently not release them. Then it causes a leak. Take a look at [Object Ownership](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB)

> You own any object you create.
>
> You “create” an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for
>   example, alloc, newObject, or
>   mutableCopy).
>
> You can take ownership of an object using retain.
>
> Remember that an object may have more than one owner. Taking ownership
>   of an object is your way of saying
>   that you need it to be kept alive.
>   (This is discussed in more detail in
>   “Accessor Methods.”)
>
> You must relinquish ownership of objects you own when you’re finished
>   with them.
>
> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message
>   or an autorelease message (autorelease
>   is discussed in more detail in
>   “Autorelease”). In Cocoa terminology,
>   relinquishing ownership of an object
>   is therefore typically referred to as
>   “releasing” an object.
>
> You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own.
>
> This is primarily an implicit corollary of the previous policy
>   rules, made explicit.

Comment: It's not autoreleased, look at my answer